# How can I change shortcut keys dynamically in form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a project in Windows form application. I want to implement dynamically shortcut keys in this application. User can change their shortcut keys as per requirement. How can I implement this dynamically shortcut keys?

Comment: Do you have to make it do that the user can change the `HotKeys`?

Comment: @Dozer789 :: Yes. I want to make HotKeys. But not predefined. User can change it as  as per requirement.

Comment: Please Some one help me...

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh while this question is rather interesting from asp.net perspective I feel that here you are asking about Windows Forms. And to make it more clear - are you are building web site or desktop application?

Comment: @AlexanderManekovskiy:: I build a desktop application project.

Comment: Override the ProcessCmdKey() method.

Comment: Shortcut keys for what??. buttons or menustrips or linklabels??

Comment: What language are you using? C#, C++, C, Java, Etc.

Comment: @Precious1tj:: For button.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I only know C# so I will try to see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that might help, I know it isn't the best way to do but I can't do any better.

```
string ii = "";

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C) && ii == "C")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your shortcut key is: C!!");
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ii = comboBox1.Text;
    }
```

Your `comboBox1` is the `ComboBox` That contains your shortcut key options.

That might help some, you will have to add a bunch of if statements. Hope this helps!!